# jQuery select only the current element when using on click

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to cleanly select only the current clicked div and not children when using `.on("click",`?

Basically I have a outer div that when faded in is 100% width and 100% height, it then has a container in the middle, my aim is to have it when you click the outer div it fades both out but not when you click on the inner div.

I've created a jFiddle here to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/silver89/kaxsL/

I've tried using `div > #box` but had no luck so looking for more suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
     $("#box").fadeIn("fast");
     return false;
});

$('div#box').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('div.inner').on('click',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You just need to stop the event from bubbling up. You can do whatever you want to select either div.
​

Comment: +1. This works even if there are other children of `#box` that *should* hide the box: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/kaxsL/26/

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `target`.  If the `target` is your `#box` then you can call `fadeOut`

```
$(document).on("click", "div > #box", function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "box") {
        $("#box").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});​
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/kaxsL/12/)**

Comment: -1.  That only works if `.inner` is the *only* child of `#box`.  If there are other descendant elements in `#box` that should close the box, they won't.  Eg, A close icon on the top right corner: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/kaxsL/27/  But using `e.stopPropagation()` works: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/kaxsL/26/

Comment: Point taken, however from the question and the markup provided there was no requirement that additional children were in `#box`.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaxsL/20/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#box", function(){
      $("#box").fadeOut("fast");
});

$(document).on("click", "#box .inner", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making the inner div independent of (e.g. not a child of) the outer div and use CSS to position the 'inner' box where you want it?

Answer (score 0):

The `event.target` is the element that received the event. If it's not `this`, it's bubbling from a descendent.

```
$(document).on("click", "div > #box", function(ev){
    if( this == ev.target )
        $("#box").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2hgW/)